# How to stop magento from removing tiers that are more than or equal to the default price?

Tags: magento

In magento i have my tiers set like so...

> Regular Price: £8.99
>   Special Price: £3.75
>
> Tiers
>
> ```
> Buy 5-9 for £3.22 each
> Buy 10-19 for £3.22 each
> Buy 20-49 for £3.22 each
> Buy 50-99 for £2.80 each
> Buy 100 for £2.58 each
> 100+ Call For Pricing
> ```
>
> With a minimum quantity set at 5 and also the regular and special price reflecting a qty > of 5.

The problem with the above being magento hides my first two tiers.

After debugging it i have found magento hides any tiers that are more than or equal to the default price / special price.

**So i suppose my question is how do i stop magento from removing the tiers that are more than or equal to the price.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your tiers appear to be lower than the special price. Is that a typo?

Either way I think you need to look in the /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php file. Specifically in the getTierPrice() function.

That is pretty much where all the magic happens (and where your prices are being removed). You may have to make changes in 2 spots in this function as part of it is used for the product page and the other for the checkout process.

Answer (score 1):

Use $_tierPrices = $_product->getData('tier_price');